# Use Facebook GraphAPI to collect page data

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know that Facebook that restricted usage of its GraphAPI, but to what extent? I want to collect data from posts of [this page](https://www.facebook.com/BillGates/) (post content, likes, shares, date). Clearly I am not an admin of this page. When I try to do this using  `{page-id}/feed` i get the message

```
{

 "error": {
"message": "(#100) Page Public Metadata Access requires either app secret proof or an app token",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "A0xAYR0R1KdoDf_6h7EPr8O"
 }
}
```

How can i collect the feed data?

Comment: Public meta data access does not cover this, the feed of a page is not meta data. You will have to submit your app for the Page Public Content Access feature, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Answer (score 1):

The [official Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/) gives the answer:

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.